# Get html in string except special element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want html structure in a string by using jQuery. But there is one element in this string which have to be be removed (table).
I have this html structure:

```
<body>
<div>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>More Text</p>
    <table>
        ... i don't need this table
    <table>
    <p>last Text</p>
</div>
</body>
```

And this is my js:

```
var content = $("body > div");
    content = $(content).html();
```

Now i want still the html structure in this string except the table-element

The result should be:

```
content = "<p>Some Text</p><p>More Text</p><p>last Text</p>";
```

How does it work?

Comment: use foreach to get `p` elements only

Comment: `$('table', $("body > div")).remove();` ?

Comment: thanks for your answer @sarath. Something i forgot to say: there are not only p elements. I want every element except table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can just `find()` the `table` within the selection and `remove()` it, like this:

```js
var $content = $("body > div").clone();
$content.find('table').remove();
var content = $content.html();

console.log(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>More Text</p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>... i don't need this table</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>last Text</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this works for the string, but with your solution the element table will be removed on my page. I need the html structure in a string (without table element) and the page should be the same

Comment: In which case `clone()` the original content. I updated the answer for you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the HTML, ignoring the `<table>`, but without removing it:

`let html = $('body > div > :not(table)').get().map(el => el.outerHTML).join('');`

This will get all elements which are not `<table>`, extract the outerHTML then join everything.

Comment: for stealing my thoughts, and for ECMA 6's Let usage. +1.